# How to vertically center WebKitView

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have a `WebKit` View that displays a camera that I have set up with constraints and all works well.  The issue I have is I want to vertically center the view so the camera shows in the middle of the screen as opposed to the very top of the view. I have not found any resources online to accomplish this. The only way I've been able to accomplish this is by centering the view myself in storyboard which when you try to zoom in on the camera it gets cut off because its not taking up the whole screen, I've attached screenshot of what I'm looking to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail in your question may be code snippet, constraints in `storyboard` etc.

Comment: Apologize - I'm somewhat new to iOS development.  How do I add constraints from storyboard?

Comment: Actually this is a long description so you can read the apple doc on auto layout  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

If you set your constraints by programmatically in coding then,

```
let imagehorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageVW!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

and I suppose you know how to set vertically and horizontally by  Storyboard.

Comment: I did not set constraints programmatically, rather through story board.

Comment: When I try to add the code you've submitted I get an error stating: "Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide.'"